# How to keep track of recursive call on my function collatz?

Tags: matlab, recursion, collatz

I am trying to keep track of how many times the function call itself. I have tried setting up num as 0 and putting num = num+1 at the end but I keep getting 1. How do I fix this?

```
function [out num] = collatz(val)
num = 0;
if val == 1
   out = 1;
elseif mod(val, 2) == 0
   out = collatz(val/2);
else 
   out = collatz(3*val+1);
end
num = num+1;
end
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible approach is to use a [global variable](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/global.html) to count the number of calls. You need to declare that variable as global

- in the workspace from which you call `collatz` the first time; and
- within the function.

The function is thus defined as:

```
function out = collatz(val)
global num %// declare as global within the function
num = num+1; %// increase call counter
if val == 1
   out = 1;
elseif mod(val, 2) == 0
   out = collatz(val/2);
else 
   out = collatz(3*val+1);
end
end
```

And then, from the command line:

```
>> clear all
>> global num %// declare as global in workspace
>> num = 0; %// initiallize to 0
>> collatz(5)
ans =
     1
>> num %// see value of num
num =
     6
```

Answer (score 0):

When you recursively call `collatz` you should save `num` too.

```
[out,num] = collatz(val/2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also avoid using `global` declarations by changing your recursive calls in `collatz` so that they output `num` as well.  You'll also need to change the base case so that `num = 0` when `val = 1`.  Therefore, do this instead:

```
function [out,num] = collatz(val)
if val == 1
   out = 1;
   num = 0; %// Change
elseif mod(val, 2) == 0
   [out,num] = collatz(val/2);  %// Change
else 
   [out,num] = collatz(3*val+1); %// Change
end
num = num+1;
end
```

You can then use `collatz` so that `num` is also output when you call it in the command prompt.  When I do this, and calling `collatz` with 5, I get:

```
[out,num] = collatz(5)

out = 

    1

num = 

    6
```